# Join Query in ACCESDB giving a IndexOutOfRangeException error

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm sure all table names are ok. I want to get the list of players of each team.

```
 public List<Speler> getSpelersPerPloeg(int ploegID)
    {
        List<Speler> spelersLijst = new List<Speler>();

        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from proj1Speler inner join proj1Ploeg on proj1Speler.ploegID = proj1Ploeg.ploegID where proj1Ploeg.ploegID = @ploegID", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ploegID", ploegID));

        OleDbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            spelersLijst.Add(new Speler((int)dataReader["spelerID"], dataReader["spelerNaam"].ToString(), (int)dataReader["ploegID"], dataReader["ploegNaam"].ToString(), (int)dataReader["spelerTypeID"]));
        }

        dataReader.Close();
        connection.Close();

        return spelersLijst;
    }
```

It trows the error with ploegID on this line " spelersLijst.Add(new Speler((...", any ideas?

And the funny thing is with sql server it works without any problem, maybe my relations in Acces are wrong?

Comment: Which line exactly throws the error?

Comment: the spelersLijst.Add(new Speler((...)

Comment: No, the constructors are fine, they work when i connect with my sql server database, it must be something with AccesDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the two tables using the *, in this way fields from both tables are returned from your query.

But what happens when you have two fields with the same name from the two different tables in the same query? Some automatic renaming occurs, the tablename is added to the two identical field names to disambiguate the column name.

So when you try to use the simple name (without the table name) you get the error. I bet that the culprit is the "ploegID" field that appears in both  tables.

I suggest to return just the field names really required by your code

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"select ps.spelerID, ps.spelerNaam, 
                                       pp.ploegID, pp.ploegNaam, ps.spelerTypeID
                                       from proj1Speler ps 
                                       inner join proj1Ploeg pp 
                                       on ps.ploegID = pp.ploegID 
                                       where pp.ploegID = @ploegID", connection);
 command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ploegID", ploegID));
 OleDbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

(Note, I am not really sure about what field is contained in which table, this is just to get the idea)

Comment: I don't understand that becouse when i used a sql server with the same tables and content it worked! And yes hes complaining with the ploegID field and that field is in both tables.

Comment: That worked, thank you man!! But how come the version i used worked in sql server?

Comment: Well, what I can say?. Access != Sql Server